# How to make django server public in rasb?

Tags: python, django, raspberry-pi

I use django server. First, I do port forwarding my raspberrypi ( my public ip : 12345) using my Sharer.

So, I can access my raspberrypi server using x-shell(putty) and then I want to access my dajngo web server. In my home I can access my django server (192.168.1.11:8000)

But I can't access my django server except my home wifi-zone.

I think i have to do port forwarding one more, but I'm not sure. Then, what can i do?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking to host a webserver/django app from your home network, to the public internet?

If so, I do not have the technical detail on how to accomplish that - but from a security perspective that is not a great idea. You might want to look into some of the free/cheap hosts out there that support python and django